# easiest way to embed googleVis $chart object into a hosted site (blogger/dropbox/Wordpress/or other)?

Tags: r, blogger

I've recently been playing with the googleVis package and I've been able to produce motion charts, but does anyone know of a tutorial that can walk someone through how to post the source code to a hosted blog (e.g., blogger, wordpress) and have the motion chart embeded?

To start assume I've got the code bock below (produced using the print() function in googleVis):

```
<!-- MotionChart generated in R 2.15.2 by googleVis 0.3.3 package -->
<!-- Tue Dec 04 12:39:01 2012 -->
<!-- jsHeader -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// jsData 
function gvisDataMotionChartIDb88676415c3 ()
{
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  var datajson =
[
 [
 "Apples",
2008,
"West",
98,
78,
20,
"2008-12-31" 
],
[
 "Apples",
2009,
"West",
111,
79,
32,
"2009-12-31" 
],
[
 "Apples",
2010,
"West",
89,
76,
13,
"2010-12-31" 
],
[
 "Oranges",
2008,
"East",
96,
81,
15,
"2008-12-31" 
],
[
 "Bananas",
2008,
"East",
85,
76,
9,
"2008-12-31" 
],
[
 "Oranges",
2009,
"East",
93,
80,
13,
"2009-12-31" 
],
[
 "Bananas",
2009,
"East",
94,
78,
16,
"2009-12-31" 
],
[
 "Oranges",
2010,
"East",
98,
91,
7,
"2010-12-31" 
],
[
 "Bananas",
2010,
"East",
81,
71,
10,
"2010-12-31" 
] 
];
data.addColumn('string','Fruit');
data.addColumn('number','Year');
data.addColumn('string','Location');
data.addColumn('number','Sales');
data.addColumn('number','Expenses');
data.addColumn('number','Profit');
data.addColumn('string','Date');
data.addRows(datajson);
return(data);
}

// jsDrawChart
function drawChartMotionChartIDb88676415c3() {
  var data = gvisDataMotionChartIDb88676415c3();
  var options = {};
options["width"] =    600;
options["height"] =    500;

     var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(
       document.getElementById('MotionChartIDb88676415c3')
     );
     chart.draw(data,options);


}


// jsDisplayChart 
function displayChartMotionChartIDb88676415c3()
{
  google.load("visualization", "1", { packages:["motionchart"] }); 
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartMotionChartIDb88676415c3);
}

// jsChart 
displayChartMotionChartIDb88676415c3()

<!-- jsFooter -->  
//-->
</script>

<!-- divChart -->

<div id="MotionChartIDb88676415c3"
  style="width: 600px; height: 500px;">
</div>
```

What is the way to get this chart to actually embed to a hosted blog?  I've tried striaght cut/paste into HTML to no avail.  I have absolutely no experience with authoring html or java code, so I'm wondering if I'm just out of luck.